# MongoDB Java Driver: Return a List of DB Records as a Single Object

Tags: mongodb-java

My question is about configuring the returned type from a MongoDB Java driver query.

I am executing a query which will return multiple objects from MongoDB. I am using the MongoDB Java driver as follows:

```
DBCollection collection = ...;
DBObject query = new DBObject("someField", "someValue");

collection.find(query);
```

This returns a `DBCursor`, which can iterate through a set of `DBObjects`. Since I want to return raw JSON, I go through each object and use a `StringBuilder` to aggregate the results into a single String (using `DBObject.toString()`). This has cased other problems though, because escape characters are included in the final result.

As an example, say I have the two records in the DB:

```
{
    someField : "someValue"
},
{    
    someField : "someOtherValue"
}
```

After getting a `DBCursor`, and building a String with a `StringBuilder`, the final result is:

```
String s = "{ someField : \"someValue\" }, { someField : \"someOtherValue\" }";
```

My ideal solution is to return a single `DBObject` and call its `.toString()` method, or (even more ideal) just get that raw straing from Mongo.

As always, any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT - ANSWERED, THANKS Mzzl**

```
private class SingleStringCollectionCallback implements CollectionCallback {

    private final DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject("someField", "someValue");
    private final DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", dbo);

    public Object doInCollection(DBCollection collection) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {

        AggregationOutput  ao = collection.aggregate(match);

        /** CommandResult contains the results list (as a BasicDBList) in its "result" field. */
        return ao.getCommandResult().get("result");

    }
}

mongoTemplate.execute(COLLECTION_NAME, new SingleStringCollectionCallback());
```

The `BasicDBList.toString()` method serializes the list into a single JSON string. Note that you should let your chosen JSON serializer handle the `toString()` call, and just pass it the `BasicDBList`. Otherwise you may find escape characters (`"{ someField : \"someValue\" }"`) in your final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query results from the aggregation framework are a single document. Perhaps you could rewrite your query to use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)? Maybe a $group by '_id' following a $match by {someField : someValue} ?

Comment: That did it. I put the detailed explanation in the question. Thanks!